Why isnt the contact force between the rack and wheel 200N?
I was looking at this YouTube video 'Example 1'  (from 4:17 timepoint) and wondering why the contact force F between the rack and wheel isn't also 200N? Isn't this constant force of 200N  being transmitted through the rack to the gear teeth and subsequently being used to pull on the wheel's gear teeth?
Rigid Bodies Impulse and Momentum Dynamics 


The force on the wheel isn't 200 N because that is impossible.
A force of 200 N would apply a torque on the gear. This would cause the teeth of the gear to accelerate.
If the rack applied a force of 200 N on the gear, the gear would apply a reaction force of 200 N on the rack. The net horizontal force on the rack would be zero, and it would not accelerate horizontally.
These things cannot both happen at once, because the teeth of the gear and the rack must have  the same velocity.

Unfortunately, the contact forces (normal forces and friction) are taught extremely poorly in most elementary physics courses, so your confusion is natural.
For rigid objects in continuous contact, such as the teeth of these gears, the normal force is exactly as large as necessary to keep the two objects from passing through each other. This is the only rule for the normal force in such situations. There is no rule saying that this has to be equal to any other force in the problem.
The right way to solve this problem is to figure out what has to be true for the teeth not to pass through each other. In this case, the velocity of the teeth of the gear must be equal to the velocity of the teeth of the rack at all times. This also means the acceleration of the teeth has to be equal to the acceleration of the rack. The normal force between the two objects will be exactly what is necessary to achieve that equality.

Many thanks for your answer.
